# Regex expression to check for string name with underscore in java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex expressions in java. How do I check if the file name has the following format `update_9_0_27` ? 
Is it something like `[0-9][\\_][0-9][\\_][0-100]` ?

Comment: Could you describe your format more? Is `update` part of the format? I am asking since you only tried to create regex for `9_0_27`.

Comment: Shouldn't `\\w+` suffice ? otherwise use `[a-zA-Z]+_\\d_\\d_[01]?\\d{1,2}`.

Comment: @Pshemo yes update is part of the file name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+_\d_\d_\d{1,2}$
```

The `^` and `$` are beginning of string anchors so that you won't match only part of a string.  Each `\d` will match a single digit, and the `{1,2}` after the final `\d` means "match between one and two digits (inclusive)".

If the `update` portion of the file name is always constant, then you should use the following:

```
^update_\d_\d_\d{1,2}$
```

Note that when creating this regex in a Java string you will need to escape each backslash, so the string will look something like `"^update_\\d_\\d_\\d{1,2}$"`.

Comment: No. In java you need double backslashes ;)

Comment: Just added that to my answer for clarity, but when asking for a regular expressions I think it makes more sense to give it in the format expected by the regex engine unless they are asking for code in a particular language.

Answer (score 2):

Are the digit positions fixed, i.e. 1-1-2?

```
^update\_\d\_\d\_\d\d$
```

Used in a Java string, you'd need to escape the backslashes

```
"^update\\_\\d\_\\d\\_\\d\\d$"
```

If by `[0-9][\\_][0-9][\\_][0-100]` you mean single-digit, underscore, single-digit, underscore, zero-to-one-hundred, and this sequence can appear anywhere in the string, then

```
".*[0-9][_][0-9][_](100|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]).*"
```

Notice that I have now used `[_]` as an alternative to `\_` for specifying a literal underscore. The last part tests for 0-100 specifically.